# Почему не получается получить private методы с помощью рефлексии?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Получаю методы вот так:

```
Method[] methods = getClass().getMethods();
```

Потом запускаю их в цикле так:

```
methods[i].invoke(this);
```

Потом пытаюсь получить все методы, в том числе закрытые вот так:

```
Method[] methods = getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
```

И запустить так:

```
methods[i].setAccessible(true);
```

Но я получаю одни и те же методы и в первом и во втором случае - только открытые, с модификатором public. Хотя в классе, из которого я получаю методы есть и закрытые. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы были близки:

```
try
{
    ClassWithPrivateMethods obj = new ClassWithPrivateMethods();

    // Способ 1: перебор всех методов класса
    Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method: methods)
    {
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(obj);
    }

    // Способ 2: вызвать по заранее известному имени метода (которое, кстати, можно узнать из 1го способа)
    Method privateMethod = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("privateMethodName");
    privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
    privateMethod.invoke(obj);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)